# Create a concatenated csv file from looping through columns of data

Tags: numpy, loops, export-to-csv, concatenation

I'm trying to iterate through a csv starting a column 17 and then have the results stack on top of each other similar to what 'pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)' does. My code is iterating through all the columns and I know why but not sure how to fix then when I export to csv spreadsheet is jumbled or doesnt display correctly.  Appreciate any help.

```
em_list=[]
for k in range(len(ad)): 
    n=ad.iloc[:,k]
    counts=n.value_counts() # *
    perc3=n.value_counts(normalize=True) # *
             .mul(100).round(1).astype(str)+'%'  # *
    df4=pd.DataFrame(perc_str3)
    em_list.append(df4)
    k=k+1
df=pd.concat(em_list)
df1=pd.DataFrame.from_records(df)
df1.to_csv()
```

Comment: Correct the indent.  Show some sample values, especially a small `df1` before the csv write.

Comment: I'm basically just trying to iterate lines of code I marked with an asterisk starting from column 17 until the end of the csv and stack the results in one dataframe

Comment: You know what properly indented Python code looks like, don't you?  Indents are important in Python.

Comment: sorry just fixed

Comment: It's hard to visualize what is happening just from reading the code.  I'd have make up some data, and and run a simplified version of your loop to see what's happening.  Can't do that on the phone.